# How to maintain two migration tables in Laravel Migration

Tags: laravel, laravel-4.2, laravel-migrations

I'm writing a custom migration and I need to maintain those migrations in a separate migration repository table. I override `DatabaseMigrationRepository` and replace the migration repository function as follows

```
public function registerRepository()
{

    $this->app->bindShared('migration.repository', function($app)
    {
        $table = $app['config']['database.cf_custom_migrations'];
        return new CustomDatabaseMigrationRepository($app['db'], $table);
    });
}
```

And I have registered my custom migration in `artisan.php`.

But when I call the custom migration command its execution is based on the Default Migration command.

Have anyone tried this before? How can run the Custom Migration command on  Custom Migration table?

Answer (score 1):

create a custom command instead of using migrate which is default to laravel.

use that custom command to run your custom migrations.

hope it helps

Comment: I have already done it if you deep dived you may realize not only creating custom command works for this. The problem is maintaining a repository table.

Comment: create a custom table and pass that table name so that it gets stored

Comment: can you tell me how to pass the table name from the custom migration command which has to be store migrations?

Comment: $table = $app['config']['database.your_custom_migration_table'];
        return new CustomDatabaseMigrationRepository($app['db'], $table);

Comment: This is described what I did up this, The problem is rewrite the migrations.repository table.